# How to return promise in angularfire 8.0 with startAt

Tags: firebase, angularfire

```
$firebase(FbRef.child('users/abc/connected_accounts/').startAt(null, 'facebook'))
  .$asObject()
  .$loaded(function(data) {
     console.log(data)
  });
```

I want to query the data which start from 'facebook' and retrieve the data from firebase. But I got these errors.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It only works without using `.startAt()`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in AngularFire - where it isn't properly supporting Firebase references where queries are applied (ie, limit, startAt, endAt). The culprit appears to be the $id property, line 608 of angularfire.js

```
self.$id = $firebase.$ref().name();
```

The name() function does not appear to exist on queries - which makes some sense since the name() function is there to provide you with the Firebase location of the object you're accessing - and a query is potentially accessing multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

startAt() is not angularFire function, it's firebase function. That means you have to call it on the Firebase reference:

```
$firebase(FbRef.child('users/abc/connected_accounts/').startAt(null, 'facebook'))
  .$asObject()
  .$loaded(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
  }
);
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html

Comment: @vzhen can you provide more debug info and the structure of your Firebase db? Where exactly 'undefined' is coming from?

Comment: I created a plunk. Please check it
http://plnkr.co/edit/qywYeRzV9z0BK4SJGMWE?p=preview

Thanks